# How is following two (same) calculations giving two different results?

Tags: functions, evaluation, warning-messages

I have the following two pieces of code which give me two different results,

```
  N[(-Kp tp + Lc - tp Lc)/(Kp tp)] /. {Lc -> 6, tc -> 0.8, tp -> 0.2, Kp -> 1/3}
```

Which gives the answer as 23 (The correct answer).

```
(-Kp tp + Lc - tp Lc)/( Kp tp) /. {Lc -> 6, tc -> 0.8, tp -> 0.2, Kp -> 1/3}
```

Which gives the answer as 3 (Which is obviously wrong).

Could anybody explain how/why this is happening and how to avoid this (possible) error?

Below is the picture of the calculation on my machine:
[image: Calculations on my machine]

Comment: You have something else defined in the notebook, because I get the same result of $71$ for both expressions. Also, 23 doesn't look like correct answer.

Comment: Yeah I just figured after copying and pasting the code. Let me try the exact version. I updated the question to include the picture.

Comment: Looks like you have both $\mathrm{\Lambda c}$ and $\mathrm{Kp}$ defined outside of this expressions. Try running `Clear[Kp, \[CapitalLambda]c]` and then evaluate this expressions again.

Comment: Yes, that worked, thank a lot for the help!

Comment: You can now post it as an answer and mark it as answered.

Comment: Is there a way to turn your comment into an answwer?